# MS UNITY: How to access to all my modules a dictionary?

Tags: c#, prism, unity-container, containers, ioc-container

I'm using MS Unity Container. And all my modules needs to use a common object where I add the values from a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Type,  Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> Maps
```

And when I use a viewModel, this one receives the common Dictionary.

A partner told me something about configure the Unity, but my knowledge about Unity is few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service and register it with unity.

For example

```
public interface ICommonDataService
{
     Dictionary<Type,Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> GetMaps();
}

public class CommonDataService : ICommonDataService
{
    public Dictionary<Type,Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> GetMaps()
    {
         //Implementation
    }
}
```

Then register with unity in your bootstrapper

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<ICommonDataService, CommonDataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

Then you can have this injected or use [ServiceLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921142%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) to resolve the instance from the interface...